# Local pdf file in webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

Im trying to load local stored pdf file to webView Controler, pdf file is next to project files. But simply nothing appears in webview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *indexPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"doc" ofType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with the UIWebView.

If you are trying to display a PDF file residing on a server somewhere, you can simple load it to your web view directly:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Or if you have a PDF file bundled with your application (in this example named "document.pdf"):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

You can find more information here: [Technical QA1630: Using UIWebView to display select document types.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html)

Comment: i noticed that i can't add webview Outlet by clicking ctrl+ and adding, when i paste @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; it is, But maybe its why it dont want to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"doc" ofType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: webview is stil empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: sadly, nothing appears again.

Comment: did you add pdf file to your project source? Did you check with name? Did you check with your webview wired? It should work.

Comment: I have tried this...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:nil];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

Comment: i have "@interface myViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;"  in .h file and synthesize webView; in .m , and the rest of the code u pasted here.

Comment: Check with your file name as `test.txt` or `test.pdf`. and Use my code for path creation, small difference in your code

Comment: It's not the point , i noticed that i can't add  webview Outlet by clicking ctrl+ and adding, when i paste @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;  it is, But maybe its why it dont want to work?

Comment: @MalcolmCartney that means, you didn't wire up your webview to your controller. Then How it will work? Check with break point, self.webview is nil or not.? always access with `self` ie self.webview.

Comment: But as i wrote i can't wire up as normal, when i push control and move mouse to the headerfile i can't insert outlet as normal, nothing appears.  Yes i tried access with self.webView

Comment: Then you should create webview and add it to baseview.

Comment: webView is added to the initial ViewControler, but it is setted up to fill up half of space.

Comment: @MalcolmCartney you should update your code with webview creation. I think, it is problem here.